# Adding a scrollbar if element doesn't fit on screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have like this:

```
        <li class="1"><a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="item1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li class="item2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li class="item3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

When i press Link, those ul items will slide down, but if theres too many of them, they slide off the screen. What i need to do so if theres many ul items and they start to slide down, it would stopp at the end of the screen and a scrollbar appears for thos ul links. Defining height isn't what i am looking for. I hope it is understandable:) Thanks.

Comment: You're not allowed to have classes or IDs starting with a number: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to limit the `li` and to prevent it from exceeding the page's "end", you need to use some jQuery/JavaScript, I believe. Here's a snippet that should do what you expect:

```
var li = $(".item2");
var ul = $(".menu");
var bottom = ul.offset().top + ul.height();
var lim = $("body").height() - bottom + li.height();
li.css({"max-height":lim, "overflow-y":"auto"});
```

Also make sure you have this in your CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 99%;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: I think some Javascript may be necessary too… I'm trying to be clever with `position: absolute;`, but it's not working like I'd hoped.

Comment: I uploaded it to here:
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://creative-events.ee/kristjan/
Pressing the second link, the items went off the screen, but know, i don't know why, there appears a scrollbar to the right side of the screen. What i would like is that it would slide as much as it can, to the bottom of the screen and the scrollbar appears inside that ul list.

Comment: @user1612619 I can't see where you inserted my snippet or anything similar. Please also look at my edit.

Comment: Yes, someone wanted to see it live, so i uploaded it. Where will i add it?

Comment: @user1612619 Right after your `menu_a.click()` stuff -- line 31 or so. Please also make sure you add the CSS I mentioned.

Comment: I now added both these and reuploaded to ftp. Now there appears two scrollbars...

Comment: @user1612619 `var li = $(".item2");` -- that should be `var li = $(".menu")`. Sorry about the bad variable name. Also, please change the `height: 100%;` in the CSS you added to `height: 99%`;

Comment: Still not quite what i need. Thanks for helping anyway:)

Comment: @user1612619 I got the problem and fixed it, take a look at the edited answer, please. I tried it and I think it works now. Can you please try it?

Comment: @user1612619 If it worked for you, don't forget to "tick" the answer to choose it, so that the question is no longer "unanswered"!

Answer (score 2):

I think all you have to do is set a max-height on the outter most li and have overflow: scroll on it

```
max-height: 50px;
overflow: scroll;
```

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yC32A/

It seems overflow: auto works as well

wit overflow: auto http://jsfiddle.net/yC32A/1/

Comment: I don't know, maybe I'm missing something, but: `Defining height isn't what I am looking for.` (From question).

Comment: @Abody97 not height, max-height as in at what point do you want it to scroll. So basically your li height will be auto until it hits that max height then it will display scroll bar. What is the concern with height/max-height?

Comment: @Huangism, the question is trying to make sure the dropdown menu doesn't go beyond the end of the screen. So the goal is to have the menu go to max-height 100% the height of the screen (not a fixed height like 50px).

Comment: Well, refer to my answer. I **think** that's what the OP wanted, but it's the same idea as yours -- just that the `max-height` value isn't static.

Comment: Yes I see that now, so a js solution is needed